# Flash Pro producing tiny components on my Android

Tags: android, flash

I have built apps with Eclipse without component size problems, but when I use Flash, the components appear tiny on my Android device. Is there any way to enlarge the size of the components or is this a drawback of using flash?

Comment: Flash? Didn't Adobe drop support for it anyway?